# Listserv - suppress reply on using email commands

Tags: email, administration

my student club uses a listserv instance provided by the university for our member mailing list, and we integrate this with our website via the email interface.

I'm currently looking into improving how things work. One thing that annoys me is that as the webmaster I receive an email notification whenever a new member gets added, because the email command to add that user is sent form the webmaster's account. (It had to be such an account because I needed to add a personal password for authentication purposes).

The "QUIET" option in Listserv only suppresses a notification to the new user, but is there an equivalent that suppresses the email confirmation sent to me as the webmaster?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress a notification you get to your own email, it is equally as simple to just set up a filter to automatically discard/archive/delete the unwanted emails.

I realize this doesn't completely answer your question, but without knowing the specific mailing list software, it's hard to tell.